# Dimensions on a STL model

Tags: solidworks, 3d-printing

I have an STL file, all I want is to be able to measure dimension from point A to point B on the model in the file. How can I do this? I do have access to Solidworks but don't know if that the best software to do this.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

'Evaluate>Measure'. Now a dialogue box appears. now select two points to know the distance. This tool can be used for measuring area, diameter, perimeter etc